# Search an array for a certain string, then return a string associated with it

Tags: c#

Currently I'm trying a personal project using C#, but I am having trouble wording my question properly on Google. For example,

```
!hello = "Hello"

!bye   = "Goodbye!"
```

Basically what I want to do is search an `ArrayList(?)` or some other data type for the keyword/string `"!hello"` and return the string `"Hello"`. How should I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: do you search about Regular Expression in google?

Comment: @SaniHuttunen, Yes you're right, maybe String.Replace() function is the one he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to hold keys and values which then allows you to get values by their key.

Eg:

```
var words = new Dictionary<string,string>();
words.Add("!hello", "Hello");
words.Add("!bye", "Goodbye!");

var hello = words["!hello"]; // returns Hello
```

You can also test if the dictionary contains a key by using `TryGetValue`:

```
string hello;
if (!words.ContainsKey("!hello", out hello))
{
    // dictionary doesn't contain key
}

hello == "Hello";
```

Comment: awesome thanks for this. I had no idea this data structure existed. I have a bit more experience in Java but have to use C# because the API has more support. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary would do the job.

> A Dictionary class is a data structure that represents a collection of keys and values pair of data. The key is identical in a key-value pair and it can have at most one value in the dictionary, but a value can be associated with many different keys.

This class is defined in the System.Collections.Generic namespace,so you should import or `using System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Initialize the dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("!hello", "Hello");
dict.Add("!bye", "Goodbye!");
```

Access it using

```
dict["!hello"]
```